# Erro ao chamar tabela DB

Tags: php, html, mysql

Sou iniciante em *MySQL* e *PHP*, e quero basicamente listar as informações que tenho na *db* em uma página *html*. Fiz o código e está retornando esses erros:

> Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string
>   given in C:\xampp\htdocs\testeman\vendo.php on line 10
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: con in C:\xampp\htdocs\testeman\vendo.php
>   on line 13
>
> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\testeman\vendo.php on line 13
>
> Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\testeman\vendo.php on line 13

Github do código: https://github.com/howdruss/AjudaStack/blob/master/Duvida

OBS: Sou novo no site e estou confuso quanto à colocar o código aqui.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verifica se esta assim:

```
<? php

$servidor = "localhost";
$usuario = "root";
$senha = "";
$dbname = "teste123";

// coneão ao banco de dados
$conn = mysqli_connect ($servidor, $usuario, $senha, $dbname);

$query = "SELECT nome, email, assunto FROM suatabela";
$dados = mysqli_query ($conn,$query);
$linha = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($dados);

 ?>
```

Estava invertida a conexao do mysqli_query, tambem percebi grande quantidade de variaveis incorreta..

Comment: Opa,desculpe-me mas poderia ser mais claro? kkk sou iniciante ainda, e me perdi um  pouco na sua resolução :/

Comment: olhando o codigo percebo uma comparaçao 
 if (total de $> 0) { 
Esta errada na primeira instancia: 
seria :

if ($total > 0){ 

Mas verificando a variavel total jamais foi criada, no codigo que passou.

Comment: eu atualizei o código lá no github: e continua   com esses erros:

Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\testeman\vendo.php on line 14

Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\testeman\vendo.php on line 15

Warning: mysqli_free_result() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\testeman\vendo.php on line 42

Comment: Agora que vi voce nao precisa disso pois esta chamando a db acima:
$db_select = mysqli_select_db ($conn ,$dbname);

e tambem e faz assim :
$query = "SELECT nome, email, assunto FROM suatabela";
$dados = mysqli_query ($conn,$query);
$linha = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($dados);
$total = mysqli_num_rows($dados)

Comment: meeeeeeee, Foi, me ajudou muuuuuuito mano <3